# How to resolve React version Error in Node Module

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

`TypeError: _react.PropTypes is undefined ./node_modules/react-inspector/lib/tree-view/TreeNode.js`

I googled it and found that PropTypes, CreateClass is removed from react 16.0.0 and I can use it like this

`var PropTypes = require('prop-types');`

Although the package has a dependency of "react": "^15.0.2",and it is installing package locally, it is not solving a problem as two versions are being conflicted with each other.

I can not change it and there are numbers of files.I really need to use it. Is there any polyfil or alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create two different projects setups. Dependencies of react 16 in one and that of react 15 in other. Deploy it in different names, using router you can use one from another. Not sure !!